# Redis SCAN command returning keys that don't match pattern

Tags: redis

So any ideas why this is happening?

```
localhost:0>scan 0 MATCH 20180223:c5*
 1)  "6553600"
 2)  
localhost:0>scan 6553600 MATCH 20180223:c5*
 1)  "655360"
 2)    1)   "20180223:c5192875:o4998561"
  2)   "20180223:c1354879:o1160565"
  3)   "20180223:c1008709:o814395"
  4)   "20180223:c4485666:o4291352"
  5)   "20180223:c4560776:o4366462"
  6)   "20180223:c1646865:o1452551"
  7)   "20180223:c3515588:o3321274"
  8)   "20180223:c938489:o744175"
  9)   "20180223:c4895806:o4701492"
  10)   "20180223:c1767235:o1572921"

localhost:0>
```

Looking at https://redis.io/commands/scan it looks this scan command is right, so I don't get what is happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may be a bug, can you reproduce it with the script below? Also, what Redis version is that? What's the size of the dataset (INFO or DBSIZE)?

Comment: Hi there, my DB has 4,000,000 keys and I am using Windows server, version 3.2.100 that I got from https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases maybe it is a bug indeed. I cannot reproduce this in Amazon ElasticCache with same data.

Comment: Aha! I have no idea whether that version has anything to do with Redis... :)

Comment: https://redis.io/download Redis do link to them, but it is an independent team that maintains it apparently. Good to know it has important bugs. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Gotcha, easiest fix - use Redis on *nix ;) (https://github.com/antirez/redis-io/pull/143)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't supposed to happen, and I can't reproduce it locally (unstable branch) using the same keys and `debug populate 10000`.

I'm using the below Lua script for testing:

```
$ cat /tmp/lua
local cursor = 0
local rep = {}

repeat
  local r = redis.call('scan', cursor, 'match', '20180223:c5*')
  cursor = tonumber(r[1])
  for _, v in ipairs(r[2]) do
    table.insert(rep, v)
  end
until cursor == 0

return rep
$ redis-cli --eval /tmp/lua
1) "20180223:c5192875:o4998561"
```